# Why are my CSS grid rows collapsing on top of each other?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am using CSS Grid Layout to replace an HTML table structure. I have two `grid-template-columns` and `grid-template-areas` with multiple rows.

All the rows appear to be over-writing one another. What have I missed?

```css
body{
  font-family:calibri, helvetica;
  color:whitesmoke;
  background:#222;
}
.table{
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(250,250,250,.4);
  border-bottom: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 75%;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header   header'
    'title    title'
    'cellLeft cellRight';
}
.header{
  grid-area:header;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(250,250,250,.4);
}
.title{
  grid-area:title;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:1.2rem;
  color:palegoldenrod;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(250,250,250,.4);
}
.cellLeft{
  grid-area: cellLeft;
}
.cellRight{
  grid-area: cellRight;
}
.row{
  text-align:center;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(250,250,250,.4);
}
.row:nth-child(odd){
  border-right:1px solid rgba(250,250,250,0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="header">
    Table Header
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    Title of Section
  </div>
  <div class="row cellLeft">
    Label 1
  </div>
  <div class="row cellRight">
    First bit of information
  </div>
  <div class="row cellLeft">
    Label 2
  </div>
  <div class="row cellRight">
    Next bit of information
  </div>
  <div class="row cellLeft">
    Label 3
  </div>
  <div class="row cellRight">
    Final bit of information
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tell your div to stand in the **same** area, use the `grid-column` placement instead `grid-area` for those repeating.

```css
body{
  font-family:calibri, helvetica;
  color:whitesmoke;
  background:#222;
}
.table{
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(250,250,250,.4);
  border-bottom: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 75%;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header   header'
    'title    title'
    'cellLeft cellRight';
}
.header{
  grid-area:header;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(250,250,250,.4);
}
.title{
  grid-area:title;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:1.2rem;
  color:palegoldenrod;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(250,250,250,.4);
}
.cellLeft{
  grid-column:1;
}
.cellRight{
  grid-column:2;
}
.row{
  text-align:center;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(250,250,250,.4);
}
.row:nth-child(odd){
  border-right:1px solid rgba(250,250,250,0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="header">
  Table Header
  </div>
  <div class="title">
  Title of Section
  </div>
    <div class="row cellLeft">
    Label 1
    </div>
    <div class="row cellRight">
    First bit of information
    </div>
    <div class="row cellLeft">
    Label 2
    </div>
    <div class="row cellRight">
    Next bit of information
    </div>
    <div class="row cellLeft">
    Label 3
    </div>
    <div class="row cellRight">
    Final bit of information
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought I had found the answer; your answer is better. +1 and chk.

Answer (score 1):

Only put the `.cellLeft` and `.cellRight` classes on the ***first two*** `.row` divs. After that, let CSS Grid manage the layout.

```css
body{
  font-family:calibri, helvetica;
  color:whitesmoke;
  background:#222;
}
.table{
  width: 250px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(250,250,250,.4);
  border-bottom: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 25% 75%;
  grid-template-areas:
    'header   header'
    'title    title'
    'cellLeft cellRight';
}
.header{
  grid-area:header;
  text-align:center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(250,250,250,.4);
}
.title{
  grid-area:title;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:1.2rem;
  color:palegoldenrod;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(250,250,250,.4);
}
.cellLeft{
  grid-area: cellLeft;
}
.cellRight{
  grid-area: cellRight;
}
.row{
  text-align:center;
  border-bottom:1px solid rgba(250,250,250,.4);
}
.row:nth-child(odd){
  border-right:1px solid rgba(250,250,250,0.4);
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="header">
    Table Header
  </div>
  <div class="title">
    Title of Section
  </div>
  <div class="row cellLeft">
    Label 1
  </div>
  <div class="row cellRight">
    First bit of information
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    Label 2
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    Next bit of information
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    Label 3
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    Final bit of information
  </div>
</div>
```